# SingleChildScrollView and Swiper not working together. Any solution to this?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-swiper

In my flutter project, I am creating a Swiper widget of images at the top portion of the screen. Along with that, I want the whole screen to be scrollable as there is content below the swiper and other widgets too.

The problem is that if I use SingleChildScrollView for the column widget of all widgets, the Swiper does not function.

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4jaR.jpg)...

[this is where i am at now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maLDO.jpg)

Here's the code

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
                  Swiper(
                    layout: SwiperLayout.CUSTOM,
                    customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(
                       //my custom swiper options
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Stack(//images,text on top of it),
                      },
                  )
                  Container(child:...//other widgets),
                  Container(child:...//other widgets),
                  ]
                )
         )  
         //SingleChildScrollView
```

Comment: Give some height to your swiper and wrap bottom grid view in Expanded widget. hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Are you using a GridView?

Comment: No I'm not using grid view

Comment: It worked!!! Now I am using GridView instead of Column widget. Thank you!